# IPNS, ENS, content hash records

Tags: ipfs

Let's say there is this ENS domain:
https://app.ens.domains/zh4ck.eth?tab=records
And it has it's content hash
ipns://k51qzi5uqu5dlodad1tur2ti64q55m1w8ipohvk0a52ebm4qlntay45hgdxqyb

But if I use any API to query the content hash for this ENS record, I get:
ipns://2D3KooWQepL1NNdw3RuvJp9f4cjUkkUZjwLHPn2HFWV6iTXVtKt
What is this second IPNS format? How can I convert this second format to the original one?

I tried Infura and Cloudflare API.

```
var ethers = require('ethers')
const provider =new ethers.InfuraProvider( "homestead" , ‘MY_API’ )
const resolver = await provider.getResolver('zh4ck.eth')
await resolver.getContentHash()
'ipns://2D3KooWQepL1NNdw3RuvJp9f4cjUkkUZjwLHPn2HFWV6iTXVtKt'
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first hash is in the older format that only encodes the content hash, while the second one is in the new format because it looks like a Base32 encoded CID (Content Identifier), used later, by IPFS, to identify a file.

Earlier versions of IPFS used a different hash function, and later versions upgraded to using CID which also includes versioning and codec information, more future-proof to support different types of content.

To convert between these formats, decode the Base32 CID to get the original hash.

Example using the `cids` library in js:

```
const CID = require('cids');
const base32Cid = '2D3KooWQepL1NNdw3RuvJp9f4cjUkkUZjwLHPn2HFWV6iTXVtKt';
const cid = new CID(base32Cid);
const contentHash = cid.toV0().toString('base58btc');
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, but does not run in my environment.  
cids@1.1.9  
const cid = new CID(base32Cid);
Uncaught Error: multihash unknown function code: 0x24  
    at CID.validateCID  
 (/Users/z/Desktop/ethers3/node_modules/cids/src/index.js:346:13)  
    at new CID (/Users/z/Desktop/ethers3/node_modules/cids/src/index.js:128:11)